# ASP.NET - Using ScriptManager in class library reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a reference to ScriptManager in my class library project instead ClientScriptManager, is it possible?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I don't understand what the issue is. ScriptManager is usually an ASP.NET Tag, not sure how you would add it in a Class Library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that you don't know how to reference the `ScriptManager` in a class library where normally these `WebControls` are not referenced. Furthermore i think you also need to know how to get a reference to the page in a static context from the class library.

To get the `ScriptManager` you have to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` in your class library project.

To get a reference to the page in a static context you need to add the `System.Web` namespace, then following returns the `ScriptManager` of the current page:

C#:

```
var http = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
if ((http != null)) {
    var page = http.CurrentHandler as Web.UI.Page;
    if (page != null) {
        var scriptManager = System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim http = Web.HttpContext.Current
If Not http Is Nothing Then
    Dim page = TryCast(http.CurrentHandler, Web.UI.Page)
    If Not page Is Nothing Then
         Dim scriptManager = System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Ok! thanks! But i have a problem, i cannot acess the method RegisterClientScriptBlock in this way. Do you know why?

Comment: The RegisterClientScriptBlock method is static/shared. Hence this will work: `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType, "ScriptKey", "YourScript", True)`